# Overriding equals and hashcode

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I have written the below program and not able to understand the output.

```
package com.demo.strings;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

class Emp
{
    private int empNo;
    private String empName;
    public Emp(int empno, String empname)
    {
        this.empNo=empno;
        this.empName=empname;
    }
    public int getEmpNo() {
        return empNo;
    }
    public void setEmpNo(int empNo) {
        this.empNo = empNo;
    }
    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }
    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if(obj != null && obj instanceof Emp)
        {
            String name = ((Emp)obj).getEmpName();
            if(name.equals(this.getEmpName()))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public int hashcode()
    {
        return (this.hashCode()+1);
    }
}

public class StringDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Emp e1 = new Emp(1,"Stack");
        Emp e2 = new Emp(1,"Stack");

        Map<Integer,Emp> empMap = new HashMap<Integer,Emp>();

        empMap.put(1,e1);
        empMap.put(2,e2);


        System.out.println(empMap.size());
        System.out.println("Both objects are equal: "+e1.equals(e2));
    }
}
```

output:2
Both objects are equal: true

I've overridden `equals` and `hashcode`, so `Map` is supposed to store only one object in it. But it appears to be storing both of them. Is the way `equals` and `hashcode` were overridden wrong? Can anyone explain me how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)

Comment: Are you sure that `hashcode()` doesn't throw a `StackOverflowError`? It will recurse infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

First read basics from [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-hashmap-in-java/)

You are using HashMap. It Stores only one unique key.

```
    Map<Integer,Emp> empMap = new HashMap<Integer,Emp>();

    empMap.put(1,e1);
    empMap.put(2,e2);
```

In above three lines you are trying to store two elements with different keys (1 and 2). So you are getting output as 
"2 Both objects are equal: true"

```
//Try this
Map<Integer,Emp> empMap = new HashMap<Integer,Emp>();

empMap.put(1,e1);
empMap.put(1,e2);
```

In this case second put will replace first value `e1` with `e2`. But as you override equals to compare `empName` field it gives output as "1 Both objects are equal: true"

If you change the declaration of `e1` and `e2` as

```
Emp e1 = new Emp(1,"Stack One");
Emp e2 = new Emp(1,"Stack Two");
```

Output will be

```
1
Both objects are equal: false
```

Comment: Its my bad. I thought i have added 
        empMap.put(1,e1);
        empMap.put(1,e2); thanks a lot Abhishek